# With Symfony, how to query entities according to user roles?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Let's say I have a `Book` entity with a field `$grantedTo`, filled with a **User Role**.
This field allows to grant or deny access to a book according to the user roles.

Let's consider another entity called `Library` with a `OneToMany` relation `$books`.

Now from a twig view, I would like to do this:

```
{{ myLibrary.grantedBooks }}
```

where the `grantedBooks` method would return me all the library books the user is allowed to see.

But to build such a method in my class Library, I would need to call something like `isGranted($book->grantedTo)`, which I believe is impossible since I **can't access the security context from within my entity**.

So I guess I should make a service where I would inject the security Context, and access this service from Twig.

I'm not sure this is the best solution, and would be glad to hear about other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a getter to your Library class, something like this:

```
public function getGrantedBook($role) {
    return array_filter($this->books, function(Book $book) use($role){
        return $book->getGrantedTo() == $role;
    });
}
```

And inside your view you'd need to pass it your current user's role.

**Edit:**

If you need to handle the case of a user with a superior role, i suggest using a doctrine entity listener and injecting @security.role_hierarchy and @token_storage into it, then in the onPostLoad event you can put your logic:

```
<service id="my_bundle.library_listener" class="AppBundle\EntityListener\LibraryListener">
    <tag name="doctrine.orm.entity_listener" entity="AppBundle\Entity\Library" event="postLoad" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.token_storage" />
    <argument type="service" id="security.role_hierarchy" />
</service>
```

in your listener:

```
class LibraryListener {

    private $roleHierarchy;
    private $tokenStorage;

    //Constructor...

    /**
     * @param Library $library
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function postLoad(Library $library, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        $library->setGrantedBooks(array_filter($library->getBooks(), function($book) use($currentUser){
            return $this->isGranted($book, $currentUser);
        }));
    }

    /**
     * isGranted
     *
     * @param Book $book
     * @param $user
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isGranted($book, $user) {

        $role = new Role($book->getGrantedTo();

        foreach($user->getRoles() as $userRole) {
            if (in_array($role, $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles(array(new Role($userRole)))))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
     }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to add a getGrantedBooks method in your Library class, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Youssef for your answer, but it won't work because if `grantedTo==User` and I'm connected as `Admin`, I should be able to see the book, but I won't because 'User' != 'Admin' (this is why security context is needed)

Comment: Great solution! At first I thought it too complicated, because you didn't inject the `authorization_checker` service instead of both `token_storage` and `role_hierarchy`, but doing so unfortunately results in a **circular reference** error. You might want to edit it though, in order to use **EntityListener** and not **EventListener** so it's called only on Library entity. This is what I did. Thanks!